# .Net MVC Multi-level data structure

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I currently have 3 models in my solution: Project, Owner, Location.

I am trying to create a table that lists all projects, including owner name and location, something like:

```
Project Name         Owner         Location
----------------------------------------------------------
Project 1            Keith         Main Office
Project 2            Brian         Asia
Project 3            Susan         Germany
```

Project model is defined as:

```
public class Project
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string ProjectName { get; set; }
    public int OwnerId { get; set; }
    public Owner Owner { get; set; }

}
```

Owner model is defined as:

```
public class Owner
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int LocationId { get; set; }
    public Location Location { get; set; }
}
```

And Location model is defined as:

```
public class Location
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Each table is linked via relationship based on the Id value:

```
Project.OwnerId => Owner.Id
Owner.LocationId => Location.Id
```

So far, I have been able to determine how to retrieve a list of all projects, and have the owner name included in the list by using the following code in my controller:

```
var projects = _context.Projects.Include(p => p.Owner).ToList();
```

What I cannot figure out is how to have the location name populated in each of the owners section of the project as well.

I have a feeling it is something simple that I am just not grasping.

Thanks in advance,
Keith Clark

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can reference child objects in your `Include()` method call.

For example:

`var projects = _context.Projects.Include(p => p.Owner).Include(p => p.Owner.Location).ToList();`

Comment: Thanks for that answer.  Knew it was probably something that was really simple and I was just blind!

Comment: wouldnt just calling `.Include("Owner.Location")` load both the owner and the location?

Answer (score 0):

You can invoke Include multiple times with child objects:

```
var projects = _context.Projects.Include(p => p.Owner).Include(p => p.Owner.Location).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks for that answer.  Knew it was probably something that was really simple and I was just blind!